# Broadcast receiver is not calling on internet connectivity check

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make a simple app which will notify if there is internet connection available or not on internet connectivity change. i have found some solution on internet and tries to implement them but somehow its not working. my broadcast receiver which i have registered on my manifest file is not calling on network connectivity change.

Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkStateChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
package com.gdm.internetconnectivitycheck;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import static android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;

public class NetworkStateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION = "com.gdm.retailalfageek.NetworkAvailable";
public static final String IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE = "isNetworkAvailable";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent networkStateIntent = new Intent(NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    networkStateIntent.putExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE,  isConnectedToInternet(context));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(networkStateIntent);
    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
}

private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(NetworkStateChangeReceiver.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.gdm.internetconnectivitycheck;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

import static com.gdm.internetconnectivitycheck.NetworkStateChangeReceiver.IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangeReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
            String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";

            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity), "Network Status: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }, intentFilter);


}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher must register the
>   following broadcasts with

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,IntentFilter)
```

> Declaring a receiver in the manifest does not work.

**CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the
>   system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers.
>   If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the
>   manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts
>   (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically). You can still
>   use a context-registered reciever when the user is actively using your
>   app.

directly from official [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

you need to register for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action at runtime from activity.
using **registerReceiver**.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChangeReceiver(), filter);
```

And don't forget to unregister.

Comment: I inserted this code in the onCreate method of my main activity and it works for me. Thanks a lot!